# Is there a card similar to Lugia from Fates Collide that targets GXs instead of EXs?

Tags: pokemon

I've dabbled in the Pokémon TCG on and off for a few years now - the main reason why I buy packs is not for the cards themselves, but for the collectible pins some of them come with. Recently, I stumbled back into it thanks to TCGO and some old boosters I'd scanned in, and I'm having a lot of fun with a water deck I cobbled together based around [Altaria EX](http://shop.tcgplayer.com/pokemon/xy-fates-collide/altaria-ex), [Seaking](http://shop.tcgplayer.com/pokemon/xy-trainer-kit-pikachu-libre-and-suicune/seaking-25), and cards that heal such as [Rough Seas](http://shop.tcgplayer.com/pokemon/xy-primal-clash/rough-seas) and [Healing Scarf](http://shop.tcgplayer.com/pokemon/xy-roaring-skies/healing-scarf) to survive longer and hit harder at the same time. Now, I've been using Lugia because it's good at surviving hits with 120 HP and Pressure and at killing EXs thanks to Intensifying Burn, which does 120 damage against EXs and 60 otherwise.

[image]

Is there a Pokémon with a move similar to Intensifying Burn that targets GX Pokémon instead of EX Pokémon? The main problem I have with the deck (besides my own lack of skill) is that it stalls against GX Pokémon because I don't have a good way to damage a 200 HP card before it collects enough energy to attack faster than I can heal it away. The knowledge that there's a card out there that can take out GX Pokémon in 2 turns, especially if it only gives up 1 prize card, would be very helpful even if I don't end up trading for it.

Answer (score 6):

A very similar card named [Golisopod (9/145)](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Golisopod_(Guardians_Rising_9)) was released in [Guardians Rising](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Guardians_Rising_(TCG)) expansion (released 5th May 2017), later reprinted with the same text as a promo (SM52) in [Crimson Invasion Single Pack Blisters](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Sun_%26_Moon_TCG_Series_merchandise#Crimson_Invasion_Single_Pack_Blisters).

> [image: Grass][image: Colorless][image: Colorless]     **Resolute Claws**     **80+**
>   If your opponent's Active Pokémon is a Pokémon-*GX* or a Pokémon-*EX*, this attack does 70 more damage *(before applying Weakness and Resistance)*.

The card has similar, but better ability than your Lugia (Golisopod takes 30 less damage instead of Lugia's 20 and also Golisopod's Ability works on Bench too). The attack requires [image: Grass][image: Colorless][image: Colorless], making it hard to use in water deck. The bonus effect of the attack works against both Pokémon-*GX* and Pokémon-*EX*, making it the card you are looking for. Both base and bonus damages are higher than Lugia's ones (60+60 vs 80+70).

[image: Golisopod GRI9][image: Golisopod SM52]

There is currently no other card that makes bonus damage to Pokémon-*GX*.

Comment: Good to know! How does this tend to work in decks? Do you bring this in to clear other threats, or is its bulk and damage sufficient to make it your main powerhouse? How well does it do competitively? (not that that was a concern for my Altaria deck)

Answer (score 3):

In addition to Golisopod, which is a commonly played card mostly for its GX but the "baby" is also often seen, you can also consider adding a [Choice Band (Guardians Rising 121)](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Choice_Band_(Guardians_Rising_121)). That card is very common and grants you a +30 attach against GX pokémon.

[image: Choice Band Card Image - The attacks of the Pokémon this card is attached to do 30 more damage to your opponent's Active Pokémon-GX or Active Pokémon-EX (before applying Weakness and Resistance).]

Answer (score 2):

[Mawile](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Mawile_(Celestial_Storm_91)) from [Celestial Storm](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Celestial_Storm_(TCG)), released August 3, 2018 has an attack that deals extra damage to Pokemon-GX:

> [image: Metal][image: Colorless] **Bite Off 20+**
>
> If your opponent’s Active Pokemon is a Pokemon-GX or Pokemon-EX, this attack does 30 more damage *(before applying Weakness and Resistance)*.

[image: Mawile]

Answer (score 1):

I did a quick Google search and Wikipedia search on this topic, and I did not find any Pokèmon cards with attacks like Lugia's Intensifying Burn that are targeted towards GXes. The Pokèmon website did come up with a Machamp GX that had an attack very much like Intensifying Burn, except that it was targeted towards evolutionary Pokèmon.